# High adjusted r square

Tags: regression, least-squares, r-squared

I am running a pooled OLS regression for my thesis. My adjusted R square is 0.74, which is quite high compared to other published studies. I have checked for normality of residuals, serial correlation and homoscedasticity. All the 3 tests meet the conditions for OLS. Should I be concerned about the high adjusted r square? Is there any test I could do to know whether the regression model has no other flaws?

Comment: Have you generated graphical diagnostic plots for the regression?  If not, that's what you should do next.  Look in particular for outlying regressor values (*e.g.*, those with large mahalanobis distance from the mean): a *single* such outlier can create an artificially inflated $R^2$ (which will inflate the adjusted $R^2$).

Answer (score 0):

The adjusted R square is what it is.  Differences with other published studies cold be due to differences in the data and/or the predictor variables.